# Linq: Descendants won't return result

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have this simpel xml file:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:com.place:dps-if-gfc-request.001">
    <ReqHdr>
        <MsgId>IE1611240000000100000001</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2016-11-24T10:14:33.327Z</CreDtTm>
        <AppInstanceId>DPSH</AppInstanceId>
        <TxId>FirstTxId</TxId>
    </ReqHdr>
    <ReqTxInf>
        <PmtId>
            <TxId>SecondTxId</TxId>
        </PmtId>
        <MsgTyp>Request</MsgTyp>
        <CtgyPurp>
            <Prtry>ECRI</Prtry>
        </CtgyPurp>
    </ReqTxInf>
</Document>
```

I'm trying to get at the content of the first  element:

```
var xml = XElement.Load (@"myLovelyXmlFile.xml");
Console.Writeline(xml.Descendants("TxId").First().Value);
```

Expecting the result to be **FirstTxId**, but nothing is coming back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting a result, because there is a namespace in the `Document` tag.

To solve this problem, declare a namespace and "add" it to the element's name:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:com.dovetailsystems:dps-if-gfc-request.001";
Console.WriteLine(xml.Descendants(ns + "TxId").First().Value);
```

This code would print "FirstTxId" to the console.

You could also temporarily remove the namespace (after removing it, don't save the document or add it again before saving):

```
public static void RemoveNamespace(this XElement container)
{
    container.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes().Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();
    foreach (var elem in container.DescendantsAndSelf())
        elem.Name = elem.Name.LocalName;
}
```

Usage of this extension method: `xml.Root.RemoveNamespace();`

After removing, your original code should work as expected.

Unfortunately it seems that there is no way to ignore the namespace; so either adding or removing it will have to do the trick...

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as soon as SO lets me. Is it possible to ignore the namespace instead?

Comment: You can remove the namespace from the element. I will update my answer.

Comment: No, no. I mean read the same file without change, and ignore the namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar. This solved so many problems for me.

Answer (score 1):

this code help you:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("YOUR_PATH");
var x= document.GetElementsByTagName("TxId").Item(0);
```

document.GetElementsByTagName get a collection of nodes that you want only first child. so we choose Item(0).